# What is the difference between assembly on mac and assembly on linux?

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

I've been trying to get familiar with assembly on mac, and from what I can tell, the documentation is really sparse, and most books on the subject are for windows or linux. I thought I would be able to translate from linux to mac pretty easily, however this (linux)

```
.file   "simple.c"
.text
.globl simple
.type   simple, @function
simple:
      pushl   %ebp
      movl    %esp, %ebp
      movl    8(%ebp), %edx
      movl    12(%ebp), %eax
      addl    (%edx), %eax
      movl    %eax, (%edx)
      popl    %ebp
      ret
.size   simple, .-simple
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.2-1ubuntu11) 4.3.2"
.section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

seems pretty different from this (mac)

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.globl  _simple
.align  4, 0x90
_simple:                                ## @simple
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    addl    (%rdi), %esi
    movl    %esi, (%rdi)
    movl    %esi, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

The "normal" (for lack of a better word) instructions and registers such as `pushq %rbp` don't worry me. But the "weird" ones like `.cfi_startproc` and `Ltmp2:` which are smack dab in the middle of the machine instructions don't make any sense.

I have no idea where to go to find out what these are and what they mean. I'm about to pull my hair out as I've been trying to find a good resource for beginners for months. Any suggestions?

Comment: The format and meaning of directives will be dependent on the particular flavour of assembler you're using. The interface with the operating system will be similarly flavoured.

Comment: @MikeW What do you mean by "flavour"? Where can I find out more information about this? I am using GCC so I'm assuming it is the GNU assembler.

Comment: The differences are mostly specific to the target executable format or are debug symbol information.

Comment: @zneak Where can I find out about the terminology, requirements and capabilities specific to me?

Comment: @zneak Sorry, the OS X side is specific to me. I tried to google most of these things, but I couldn't find anything that was specific to the command I was looking for. It would always be embedded in more assembly code in a question or example completely unrelated to what I wanted to know. Maybe I am not using the right key words for my searches?

Comment: `Ltmp2:` is just a code label to which you could jump (even though nothing jumps there). I'm not a great expert in the matter, but googling the exact names of the commands `cfi_startproc` and `cfi_endproc` gave me decent results (they denote the start and the end of a function, and are used for exception handling).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To begin with, you're comparing 32-bit x86 assembly with 64-bit x86-64. While the OS X [Mach-O](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) ABI supports 32-bit IA32, I suspect you want the [x86-64 SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). (Thankfully, the [x86-64.org](http://www.x86-64.org/) site seems to be up again). The [Mach-O x86-64](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/x86_64_code.html) model is essentially a variant of the ELF / SysV ABI, so the differences are relatively minor for user-space code, even with different assemblers.

The `.cfi` directives are [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging directives that you don't strictly need for assembly - they are used for call frame information, etc. Here are some minimal examples:

ELF x64-64 assembler:

```
    .text
    .p2align 4

    .globl  my_function
    .type   my_function,@function

my_function:
    ...
.L__some_address:

    .size    my_function,[.-my_function]
```

Mach-O x86-64 assembler:

```
    .text
    .p2align 4

    .globl  _my_function

_my_function:
    ...
L__some_address:
```

Short of writing an asm tutorial, the main differences between the assemblers are: leading underscores for Mach-O functions names, `.L` vs `L` for labels (destinations). The assembler with OS X understands the '.p2align' directive. `.align 4, 0x90` essentially does the same thing.

Not all the directives in compiler-generated code are essential for the assembler to generate valid object code. They *are* required to generate stack frame (debugging) and exception handling data. Refer to the links for more information.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was aware of the differences between 64 and 32, but despite how simple the answer was, you'd be surprised how hard it was to get such a straight answer about the directives. Its good to know that they don't immediately affect the assembly. Is there a way I can find out exactly what they mean?

Comment: Note that for x86 Linux, `.align 4` = `.balign 4` = `.p2align 2`.  While on Mac, as you say it's `.p2align 4`.  Never use .align, always one of the unambiguous .balign or .p2align directives.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the Linux code is 32-bit Linux code. Note that 64-bit Linux can run both 32- and 64-bit code!

The Mac code is definitely 64-bit code.

This is the main difference.

The ".cfi_xxx" lines are only information used for the Mac specific file format.

Comment: Linux also uses DWARF `.cfi` stack-unwind metadata with those same directives; perhaps the OP used compile options like `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` to omit them.